# How to assign group_id using attributes course and faculty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new at RubyOnRails and
I want to create user with assigning it to group but the problem is that user doesn't know group_id,
user only know his/her course and faculty is. I need to find group_id by course and faculty

```
Group has_many :users
User belongs_to :group 
I added migration AddGroupIdToUsers group_id:integer

 new.html.erb

 <% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
 <h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="span6 offset3">
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :surname %>
  <%= f.text_field :surname %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <label for="person_group_id">Group:</label>
  <%= collection_select(:group,:id,Group.all,:id,:course, :prompt => "Select a Group")%>

  <label for="person_faculty_id">Faculty:</label>
  <%= collection_select(:group,:faculty,Group.all,:id,:faculty, :prompt => "Select a Faculty")%>

  <%= f.label :id, "Group_ID" %>
  <%= f.text_field :group_id %>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

thank you very much!

Comment: Can you try this?  <%=  f.collection_select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to accomplish this would be to use simple_form

All you have to do is:

```
<%= f.association :group %>
```

and it'll automatically create a drop down for you with Group.all

You can pass in as: :radio, as: :collection, whatever best suits your needs.

See: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

And your form would be much cleaner as well.

It would look like below (untested):

```
<%= simple_form_for (@user) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

  <%= f.input :name %>

  <%= f.input :surname %>

  <%= f.input :email %>

  <%= f.input :password %>

  <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.association :group%>

  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hes using `form_for` not `simple_form`

Comment: I know... simple_form is better suited for newbies... specially when trying to create associations.

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes it very easy, but the think is that I want to learn how to do it by myself.Anyway thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line

```
<%= collection_select(:group,:id,Group.all,:id,:course, :prompt => "Select a Group")%>
```

Try this

```
<%= collection_select(:user,:group_id,Group.all,:id,:course) %>
```

the syntax for `collection_select` is `object,method,collection,value_method,text_method,options,html_options` this is stating

```
<select name="object[method]">
   <option value="value_method">text_method</option>
   <option value="value_method">text_method</option>
   <option value="value_method">text_method</option>
   ....
</select>
```

or in your case

```
<select name="user[group_id]">
   <option value="1">Course 1</option>
   <option value="2">Course 2</option>
   <option value="3">Course 3</option>
   ....
</select>
```

Obviously edit this line in the appropriate manor as well

```
<%= collection_select(:group,:faculty,Group.all,:id,:faculty, :prompt => "Select a Faculty")%>
```